# In 2011 is it truly necessary to still degrade js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, graceful-degradation

Serious question.

I tried most of the famous websites (including facebook) and I can say that tons of functionality doesn't degrade at all with js disabled. I've been always told that js should degrade gracefully, but does this still applies in these day and age?

ie6 support is being dropped by several sites, and most of the web2.0 relies heavily on js (especially ajax, I even found some sites that doesn't let you login without js enabled).

What are your thoughts about it?

EDIT:

I want to add that I for one develop webapps without js first and then enhancing them with it. The issue is that year after year js is more and more a part of the web. HTML5, canvas and heavy js apps are starting to rise. Will we ever reach the point where js will be compulsory in most of the websites? I talked about facebook because the site actually degrades and is usable without js but most of the functionalities and shortcuts are stripped to the poin that the site feels dull and old. There are also example where js is better than server side scripting, for instance the ordering of large tables is faster and less server intensive that a php implementation.

p.s. I don't know how to make this a community wiki, but I will, I'm just interested in your opinions.

Comment: My phone would appreciate it if you didn't drain it's battery.  Thanks! :)

Comment: should probably be moved to programmers or webmaster stack exchange

Comment: @dvhh - I don't know about having to move it, but perhaps it should be made community wiki.

Comment: Maybe these sites are famous/popular because they do not require Javascript?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In 2011 there are still several important types of users for whom you can't assume javascript will function properly:

- search robots
- browsers for visually impaired users
- feature phones
- corporate browsers, thin clients, etc still using IE6 or whatever
- REST-based clients by fellow developers
- your frontend usability testing tools
- weird new browsers like my mom's Roku TV box

So I think it's still best to offer graceful degradation.

Comment: This is actually the only real answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

Even if it isn't necessary, I still prefer to write applications that **don't** need JS enabled.

I don't think there is much audience for non-JS versions of your web apps, and even if there were, who cares? It's such a small percentage of people, you're not going to annoy very many people by forcing them to upgrade their browsers.

**However, I don't write degrading JS for my users, I write it for me...**

In fact, I don't write degrading JS at all - I write *enhancing* JS.

I feel that I can write applications with more direction and success if I **first write them without JavaScript**, and **add the JavaScript later to enhance the application**.

Comment: Agree entirely. I always write my web apps without javascript initially, then add javascript where it would enhance the site. Obviously you come across some features that just aren't doable without javascript, but those features are very rarely so important as to prevent the core feature set from being usable.

Comment: +1, nice response.  I like the idea of writing a site/application that is not dependant on it, and then is merely enhanced by its presence.

Comment: +1 I think that's an excellent approach.

Comment: +1 Am using the same approach as above but mainly for SEO. Users who have javascript disabled are in almost all cases very well aware of this.

Comment: +1 I hate to feel degraded after writing JS.

Answer (score 13):

As always with these questions, the answer is *it depends*.

It depends on *your* audience (which will likely differ widely from any generic browser statistics you can find).

How many of them have JavaScript disabled? Do you care about those users? If not, then sure, don't degrade gracefully.

That said, at the very least, I'd recommend you at least make your website usable and navigable without JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

The site should "work". It doesn't have to sing or dance, but it shouldn't exclude anyone without JS.

Most screen readers still don't use JS, so all your content should be available to them.

Answer (score 3):

Who is your target? Geeks, or employees of companies (or worse, military institutions) where javascript is banished ?

It's still good to know how to degrade, even if you don't have to apply it 100% for every app you make.

Comment: In Soviet Russia, JavaScript degrades you!

Answer (score 2):

I think that javascript is a technology and that should cost it to improve not to degrade, we cannot degrade technology just because it could effect minor community and not just because it  could bring some threat.